# Activating parent link with keyboard focus on tabbable child without Javascript?

Tags: html, hyperlink, accessibility, tabindex

Consider a situation like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dxag37hc/):

```
<a href="#">
    <div tabindex="0">Tab focus me, then ⏎</div>
</a>
```

If I'm focused on the `<div />` and press enter, I get different behaviour across the major desktop browsers (OS X Yosemite):

- Chrome 54.0.2840.71: The parent link is not activated. Both the `<a />` and child `<div />` are separately selectable by tab.
- Firefox 48.0.2: The `<a />` doesn't seem to be selectable by itself, but the link can be activated with focus on the `<div />`.
- Opera 39.0: Same behaviour as Chrome.
- Safari 9.1.2: Like Firefox, the `<a />` itself isn't selectable, but when the `<div />` is selected, the link *isn't* activated.

Since `<a />` can't be nested, is there any way to make a focused child element activate the parent link across browsers without Javascript? The Javascript option is obvious, but I find it somewhat unbelievable something this simple would need it.

Comment: I think you are trying to solve a problem that does not exist. Do you have a sample page or description of what you are trying to achieve? In your example, the `tabindex` is completely unnecessary since the `<a>` will receive focus and there is no other child element that could be at play. Hence the need for a real example or scenario.

Comment: What's the bigger picture here - why are you trying to nest interactive elements? Can you give an example of what this UI might look like in the real world? There may be another way of getting the end result you are after that avoids this...

Comment: Sorry for the lack of a non-toy example, I'm in the process of making a more illustrative one.

Comment: In the process of implementing [this example](https://acrylic-origami.github.io/acrylic-origami.github.io/40442421.html), I see that there is no need for this. Originally, I intended for the entire card to be clickable with "Read more" as a target for mouse users — the link giving more context to screenreader users. In the end, though, a link on "Read more" really suffices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any element with a tabindex is considered as an `interactive content`

See:
http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#kinds-of-content-interactive-content

> The tabindex attribute can also make any element into interactive content.

And those interactive elements can not belongs to a `a[href]` tag

> The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, **so long as there is no interactive content within**

So you won't be able to achieve that without javascript as it's not something that your browser should do normally.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for linking and referencing the spec. 

"It's not something that your browser should do normally" — I know browsers prevent `<a />` from nesting and violating this rule by restructuring the hierarchy ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skhv945a/)). How unsafe is the `a > [tabindex]` structure in older browsers, since the latest versions don't restructure?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way out of this without JS.
The question is how do you test what is focused ?
Try this:

```
setInterval(function(){
  console.log(document.activeElement);
},1000);
```

I've tested on FF and Chrome and you can focus on anchor and div ... but the link will fire only from anchor which seems to be quite obvious.

BTW: Why do you even need this tabindex ?

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of an example or use case, and given Adam's answer above, I would also like to point out that activating a link (whether directly or indirectly) by just focusing any part of it is a violation of WCAG 2.0 Success Criterion 3.2.1. This is a level A item (meaning you cannot pass level AA compliance with any failed level A tests).

> [3.2.1: On Focus: Level A](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/consistent-behavior-receive-focus.html)
>
> When any component receives focus, it does not initiate a change of context.

"Change of context" would cover loading a new page/URL.

In short, not only does the HTML specification tell you not to nest interactive content, the WCAG specifically forbid changing the page just by focusing an element.

In short, **do not do this**. Even if you *can* do it with JavaScript (I am not going to even try), then your project will fail basic accessibility guidelines (and be violating laws in some countries). This also means you are opening your employer/client up to litigation (assuming just making a terrible, inaccessible user experience is not enough of a reason).

Comment: If I bind a change of context to some "onfocus" event, I  can understand it as a violation of this spec. Isn't it distinct though to initiate a change of context on pressing enter or clicking on an arbitrary focused element?

Comment: Clicking (or tapping or pressing Enter) on a button or link, for example, typically changes context and is expected (exceptions are where they change the existing page, though that can also be a change of context). Putting focus on a button/link, however, does not change context, nor should it. Whether the element is focused when you click it or not has no bearing in this case. Consider users of both mouse and keyboard, who may tab through a page but then click on an element somewhere else.

Comment: "Putting focus on a button/link, however, does not change context, nor should it." I totally agree. Focusing on the link's child in this case (cf. the JSFiddle in my question) doesn't change the context, nor do I want it to — only clicking, tapping or pressing enter would, like your standard link/button.

Comment: Then what is the purpose of making the child element focusable when the parent can already receive focus? I do not understand what you are trying to achieve and your question sounds like you want the parent to activate when the child receives focus.

Comment: @Alohci, I am not sure how this relates to my answer. But putting a focusable element inside another interactive element is a problem. Not being able to access the image's context menu is also a problem. You have to sort out an interface that addresses both.